# ajax append something if condition is verified

Tags: ajax, if-statement, append

How do i make this working?

```
                        var makePage = $('<div />').attr('data-role', 'page').attr('id', 'p'+item.id)
                        .append($('<div>').attr('data-role', 'header')
                        .append('<a href="#"></a>')
                        .append('<img src="images/app/logo.png" id="navImg"/>')
                        .append('<div class="separatore"></div></div>'))
                        .append($('<div />').attr('data-role', 'main').attr('class', 'ui-content')
                        .append('<h2 class="hstyle">'+item.name+' '+item.surname+'</h2>')
                        .append($('<ul />').attr('data-role', 'listview').attr('data-inset', 'true') 
                if (item.cellulare != '') {     .append('<li><a href="tel:+39'+item.cellulare+'"><img src="images/app/tel.png" class="ui-li-icon">'+item.cellulare+'</a></li>')  }
                        ) // data-role page
                        ); // data-role main                      

                        makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
```

the condition i want is "if variable item is not empty, append this..".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your new div into a variable if you want to later append new elements onto it. The way you were doing it you were telling the compiler to use the append method of a true value which doesn't exist.

```
var newDiv = $('<div />').attr('data-role', 'page')
                         .append($('<div>')
                         .attr('data-role', 'header');

if (item != '') {
 newDiv.append('<a href="#"></a>')
        .append('<img src="images/app/logo.png" id="navImg"/>');
}
```

If you need to append into specific elements you need to append at that level then put that level into the parent. For instance if you were trying to append the image inside the anchor (note your code if it were to be proper code would append all into the first div you created):

```
$('<a href="#"></a>').append('<img src="images/app/logo.png" id="navImg"/>').appendTo(newDiv);
```

In your first part it looks like you possibly were intending to create a div and then append another div with a specific data-role, but the way you were doing it would create a div with data-role page, append another div, and then update the parent div's data-role to header. To do it in order you should do:

```
var newDiv = $('<div />').attr('data-role', 'page');
$('<div>').attr('data-role', 'header').appendTo(newDiv);
```

Comment: but i need to append respecting the order.

Comment: That does append in the same order you were attempting. Were you trying to append the image inside the anchor?

Comment: When you chain the appends the way you were attempting they all just dump into the first element. If you need a specific ordering create variables for those entry points and append to the parent.

Comment: i ahve some problems, because i have to respect some orerds. in particular, i have to use this method to append a <li> into a <ul> that is included into a <div>.

Comment: @Tony33 and my comments still stand. You CANNOT just randomly drop a `.append` and hope it to work. You need to build up a structure first. When you just chain `.appends` it will append to the first selector not to subsequent elements. So create your base element as a variable. Then create the subsequent elements you want to append to that element and then append them in the order you want.

Comment: Your edit also has errors int he code (missing `)` in places). Make certain you are viewing your console to see any errors that might be in your code.

Comment: can you edit your answer to match my edited code? because i'm getting really confused... :S

Comment: update your question with the actual structure you are attempting to make as you seem to be just appending everything to the single div.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this.

```
if(item != '')
{
  //write your code 
}
```

you are mixing code